# PHP compare multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, compare

This dificult to explain so forgive me if it is not water clear...

I have 2 identical associative arrays.

**First and second arrays are identical, so i only put one here:**

```
"parameters": [
            {
                "code": "video",
                "type": "input",
                "labels": {
                    "pt": "Vídeo Youtube",
                    "en": "Youtube video"
                },
                "required": false,
                "purpose": "add",
                "options": null
            }
];
```

The first one send values that come via form $_POST to a an API and the labels are send in "EN" language.

But, The second one send values to a mysql database and the labels must be send in "PT" language. This second one array must change only the labels from EN to PT. The rest of the fields values must be identical to what the first array sends to the external API.

I'm trying to compare both arrays and change only the labels key translation to PT based on what the first array is sending to the API.

Example:
first array has: "code" => "video", labels => "EN"
second array must have:  "code" => "video", labels => "PT"

I'm stuck trying to make with work... any help, please...

Comment: Store one more key in the array, like `label_lang`. It will have value of either `EN` or `PT`. Based on its value, you update `label` and `label_lang` values accordingly.

Comment: I'm sending all the data that is in array1 to a single column in JSON format.

Comment: I have another column in the database to store array2 data. And in that array2 data column i need only to receive PT labels instead of EN. The rest of the data remain equals to array1.

Answer (score 0):

here is a small class for you:

```
class ArrayDiffer
{
public static function recursiveDiff(array $firstArray, array $secondArray): array
{
    $difference = [];

    foreach ($firstArray as $key => $value) {
        if (\array_key_exists($key, $secondArray)) {
            if (\is_array($value)) {
                $recursiveDiff = self::recursiveDiff($value, $secondArray[$key]);
                if (\count($recursiveDiff)) {
                    $difference[$key] = $recursiveDiff;
                }
            } else {
                if ($value != $secondArray[$key]) {
                    $difference[$key] = $value;
                }
            }
        } else {
            $difference[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $difference;
}
}
```

and here is the test, which demonstrates how it works:

```
public function testDiff(): void
{
    $arrayDiffer = new ArrayDiffer();

    $firstArray  = \json_decode(
        '[{
            "code": "video",
            "type": "input",
            "labels": {
                "en": "Youtube video"
            },
            "required": false,
            "purpose": "add",
            "options": null
        }]', true
    );
    $secondArray = \json_decode(
        '[{
            "code": "video",
            "type": "input",
            "labels": {
                "pt": "Vídeo Youtube"
            },
            "required": false,
            "purpose": "add",
            "options": null
        }]', true
    );

    $this->assertEquals(
        [
            0 => [
                'labels' => [
                    'en' => 'Youtube video',
                ],
            ],
        ],
        $arrayDiffer::recursiveDiff($firstArray, $secondArray)
    );
}
```